# I am using IBM Cloud Object Storage and want to read a pdf file from the storage and want to store its text content in form of string

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I have used ibm_boto3 as mentioned in the IBM COS documentations. I have defined the resources as following:

```
cos = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
    ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
    ibm_service_instance_id=SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID,
    ibm_auth_endpoint=COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
    endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
)
```

Following is the code that I am using to get the content of the pdf file:

```
def get_item(bucket_name, item_name):
    print("Retrieving item from bucket: {0}, key: {1}".format(bucket_name, item_name))
    try:
        file = cos.Object(bucket_name, item_name).get()
        file_content = file["Body"].read() #returns data in bytes
        #print("\nFILE:-------------------------\n", file) #shows the meta data of the object
        return file_content
    except ClientError as be:
        print("CLIENT ERROR: {0}\n".format(be))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to retrieve file contents: {0}\n".format(e))
```

The object is of **ibm_botocore.response.StreamingBody object** type.
I am not able to convert the data obtained in bytes to string. I have tried decoding with **utf-8** and **base64** but doesn't work. I get the following **error** when I try and decode with **utf-8**:

**Unable to retrieve file contents: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte**

I am also unable to figure out what type of encoding is used by IBM COS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you search around? COS is using S3. Tried you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799852/read-pdf-object-from-s3